# iPad uisplitviewcontroller left view become balck

Tags: ipad

In one of my ipad project, uisplitviewcontroller left view becomes black.
But when I rotate iPad the orientation is portrait, left window display over the left winodw 
Is there anyone met the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your geometry. Check the frame that you set to your left viewControllers view.

Hope this'll help

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue as well. This happened to me only when I was not dismissing the UIPopOver in the Potrait mode before rotating it to Landscape mode.

So I dismissed the PopOver within the method:

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

if(defaultview)
defaultview.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;

if (pc) {
    [self dismissPopup];
}
```

}

And added the method in my DetailedViewController (the same view controller which had the above UIPopOverDControllerDelegate method)

```
-(void) dismissPopup{
if(pc)
{
    [pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [pc release];
    pc = nil;
    isPopOverClosed = YES;
}
```

}

Thus by dismissing and releasing the object 'pc', when I rotate, the blackening of the left view goes away.

So far so good. But I face a problem after the above step:

**The left view of the SplitView slightly displaced downwards.**

- This happens only when I rotate the
  iPad simulator from Potrait to
  Landscape when theUIPopOver is
  already open.
- If I manually close it    in Potrait
  mode by clicking outside    the
  PopOver or clicking the PopOver
  BarButtonItem on the left of the
  toolbar, and then rotate the screen
  to landscape, I do not face this
  issue.The left view of the
  SplitViewController is perfectly
  positioned.

  Any clue why this may be happening?

Comment: You'll probably get better response if this is its own question.